# How long before receiving downloads on android app?

Tags: android

I recently uploaded an app to Google play and it is published, the only weird thing is that there have been 0 downloads in the 12 hours period since they were published. Is this common or will installs come slowly and then speed up?

Comment: Marketing..... ever heard of that?

Comment: Yeah I just thought maybe that it would get a few downloads by it self but i guess not at this rate

Comment: http://appflood.com/blog/ten-alternative-android-app-stores
this link ca help you

Comment: There are  loads and loads of apps on the playstore,its difficult (nearly impossible) that the application you uploaded 12 hrs. ago may pop up in front of the users.Try sharing some links on social media(not here on StackOverflow,you will not be welcomed) .Make some pages on facebook,Let your friends,enemies and frienimies know.They will download,Will praise or criticize,In one or another way your application is now being downloaded by some....and then sit back and Hope this will lead to a chain reaction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you have to market the product to get downloads.
Even if you downloaded the app in some of your devices the count may still shown as 0 because:

1. Google updates download count in range only. if you have 5+
   Downloads, then it will display 5-10.If you are having only 3, then
   you have to wait until you get 3 more.
2. "Application statistics are
   updated daily." Will take time to update the download statistics.